# Passing a php variable from a form input into a href link that is part of an echo

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, url

The input..

```
<input class="myButton" style="width: 60px" type="number" min="1" max="200" step="1"  name='pages' value='<?php echo "$pages";?>'/>
```

My attempt to pass the variable $pages

```
if(count($uploadedFiles)>0){
                        echo "<b>Uploaded:</b>";
                        echo "=";
                        foreach($uploadedFiles as $fileName)
                        {
                            echo " ".$fileName.",";
                        }
                        $var=$_POST['pages'];
                        echo '<br><a href="http://www.myurl.com/index.php?pages=';$_GET["var"];" target="_blank">View Pages</span></a>';
                                            }                                           
                }
                else{
                    echo "ERROR: Please press the browse button and select a CSV file to upload.";
                }
```

This does not add the desired number so the clicked URL becomes..
`http://www.myurl.com/index.php?pages=x` (where x is the number entered in the form)

Comment: So many little errors in here... are you not getting syntax errors or weird attribute values in your html?

Comment: Not that i know to, if i just display a plain url (slashed out due to it being part of an echo) as in echo "<a href=\"http://www.myurl.com/index.php\" target=\"_blank\"> View Pages</a>"; It functions as I expect. My problems start with this as soon as i try and pass the variable as part of the url

Comment: 1) You can save yourself a lot of quote escaping hassle if you use single and double quotes, e.g. `echo '<input value="..." ... />'`. 2) You have an extra closing brace `}` before `else` that is not paired. 3) You forgot to escape these double quotes in array access: `p?pages=$_GET["pages"]\"`. 4) Here you concatenate a variable within double quotes (has no effect and outputs literal dots): `echo "<a href=\"http://www.myurl.com/index.php?pages=.$pages.`. You need to familiarize yourself with string syntax a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your help and tips, I have updated my OP after all this time reading and trial and error I still cannot get it to pass the variable to the link.

Comment: When using single quotes, you need to concatenate variables: `pages=';$_GET["var"];` - those semicolon should be dots.

Comment: updated to <a href="http://www.myurl.com/index.php?pages=.$_GET["var"]." target="_blank">View Pages</a> and just get a blank white page.

Comment: I've took a completely different approach to this now and got it working. Many thanks for your help and pointers.

<form action="myurl.com/index.php?pages=$pages" method="get" target="_blank">

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a completely different approach to this now and got it functioning as I'd like.

Many thanks for your help and pointers.

```
<form action="myurl.com/index.php?pages=$pages" method="get" target="_blank">
```